# How to to put fetched data into the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

---

I am trying to put fetched data into the state but it's not working, please let me know what I am doing wrong here, and also I want specific data to be inside the state like in this example I want only questions, answers, and incorrect answer, also I wanted to put the whole data into the array of object

```
const [quiz,setQuiz]=useState({});

useEffect(()=>{
  const  getQuizData =async ()=>{
  const res = await fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
  const data = await res.json();
  setQuiz({data});
  }
  getQuizData();


},[])
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what coming from your data is below. I suspect what you want is setQuiz(data.results) also initializing like useState([]) should help too.

```
const data = {
  response_code: 0,
  results: [
    {
      category: 'History',
      type: 'multiple',
      difficulty: 'medium',
      question: 'Joseph Smith was the founder of what religion?',
      correct_answer: 'Mormonism',
      incorrect_answers: ['Buddhism', 'Christianity', 'Hinduism'],
    },
    {
      category: 'Sports',
      type: 'multiple',
      difficulty: 'medium',
      question: 'In a game of snooker, what colour ball is worth 3 points?',
      correct_answer: 'Green',
      incorrect_answers: ['Yellow', 'Brown', 'Blue'],
    },
  ],
};
```